# bootstrap drop down menu not shown in IE 11

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I'm facing an issue with the bootstrap dropdown menu with IE 11 on windows 7.

The dropdown menu simply doesn't show when I click on the button. Nothing happen except JS error which is : script65535 invalid calling object.

Any clue ?

Here is my code :

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="right: 0; left: auto;" role="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="link1">item1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a target="blank" href="link2">item2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>
        <a target="blank" href="link3">item3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The head part with CSS and JS library used :

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Bootstrap JS and jQuery UI tend not to play nice with each other. I would recommend using one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is coming from JS bootstrap and Jquery version...

replaced :

```
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

By :

```
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And it's working now.